# Derby Issue - couldn't establish connection with db

Tags: artifactory, derby, jfrog-cli

Whenever I am trying to start my Artifactory service, I am met with the following error in console.log:

> 2020-12-14T14:51:32.840Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [794f6381e66d1900] [tifactoryHomeConfigListener:59] [ocalhost-startStop-2] - Failed initializing Home. Could't establish connection with db: jdbc:derby:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/artifactory/derby;create=true
> 2020-12-14T14:51:32.844Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [794f6381e66d1900] [actoryContextConfigListener:82] [ocalhost-startStop-2] - Failed initializing Artifactory context: Artifactory home not initialized.

I did download the latest derby jar available over Apache and have put it under tomcat/lib folder as well still the issue persists.

The setup was working fine since a very long time but with a sudden maintenance activity over the servers, the above mentioned error has been an uninvited guest which simply doesn't let Artifactory start.

Answer (score 3):

As you have mentioned an unplanned maintenance activity caused the issue, I suspect the stale derby lock file is causing the problem here. As you might aware, Artifactory uses the embedded Derby database, it won't allow more than one connection at a time. Hence removing the lock (from /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/artifactory/derby) will allow the Artifactory to make a connection with the derby.
In addition to that, please don't forget to remove the downloaded derby file as Artifactory comes bundled with the required dependencies.

Comment: I have tried removing the db.lck file as well and then starting the service. But the error isn't "Another Instance of Derby is Running" but that of the one as been mentioned in the question. Even I thought the db.lck would be the issue, but the conection isn't happening in the first place. I myself tried to check the connection as suggested in https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-connect-to-a-derby-db-and-run-different-queries/ which works fine on stand-alone basis but not sure what really happens once the service is started.

Comment: did you make sure there is no java process running? generally the error indicates a process already running.

Comment: yep...i did make sure of it. even checked if any other instance of either artifactory or tomcat is running for that sake. there wasn't any other instance running. still the issue persists :/

Comment: **NOTE**: There seems to be some kinda bug with the version of 7.4.3 as well if you decide to opt for postgresql. Using postgresql leads to the following error:
"ERROR: type "blob" does not exist".
If you create the table yourself in postgresql for which the error occurs and then re-run artifactory, it complains about relationship existence issue.

The best option would be to opt for mysql in that case.